# Scriptblock with IF statement as parameter of function

Tags: powershell, parameters, scriptblock

I have this script file contains:

```
   function run_command 
{
    param    
    (
        [string] $scriptblock
    )

    $sb = [Scriptblock]::Create($scriptblock)
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
}

$a = "aaa"

$scriptblock = @"
if($a){echo $a}
else {echo nene}
"@

run_command -scriptblock $scriptblock
```

I have two problem:
1. If the scriptblock contains IF statement, the execution failed with error like "The term 'someofArguments' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...".

But without IF statement everything is working fine. So how to send that scriptblock with IF statement?

2. How to avoid using backtick in $command with variables $true, $false and mainly $null? Because without backtick they are translated to true,false and *nothing*.

Thank you.

PS: I found this topics [PowerShell function with parameterized script block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688238/powershell-function-with-parameterized-script-block) and similar posts, that are saying to send scriptblock as string and in function itself convert it to type scriptblock.

EDIT:
I figure out this solution, but it is not very nice. Do someone know easier solution than put backtick like this?

```
$scriptblock = @"
`$a=`"$a`"
if(`$a){echo `$a}
else {echo nene}
"@
```

Comment: Please optimize the formatting of your posting (format all code as code).

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quotes in a here-string.